# Converting complicated html table to array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, html-table

I am working on an ionic app for college students so they can see their grades, in the college website the grades are shown in a table I want to parse that table to an array of objects so I can show that information the app in form of cards.

I want to convert a complicated table to array of objects using Javascript. I tried parseTable.js but it only work well with simple tables.

P.S. I can't change anything in the html code.

This is the table I want to convert:

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th>Unite d'Enseignement</th>
            <th>NB_ECTS</th>
            <th>MOYENNE /UE</th>
            <th>MODULES</th>
            <th>COEF</th>
            <th>MOY_MODULE</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Application d'entreprise</td>
            <td>
               <span>9</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>13,69</span>
            </td>
            <td</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>12,23</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Architecture n-tiers .NET</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>14,25</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SharePoint</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>14,60</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Architecture Ntiers</td>
            <td>
               <span>5</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>11,30</span>
            </td>
            <td>JEE specifications and applications</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11,30</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Communication, Culture et Citoyenneté  A4</td>
            <td>
               <span>3</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>14,20</span>
            </td>
            <td>Communication, Culture et Citoyenneté  A4</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>14,20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Communication, Culture et Citoyenneté  F4</td>
            <td>
               <span>3</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>10,25</span>
            </td>
            <td>Communication, Culture et Citoyenneté  F4</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>10,25</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Gestion de projet et management</td>
            <td>
               <span>6</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>11,57</span>
            </td>
            <td>Environnement de l’entreprise</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>13,05</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Gestion de projet</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>14,50</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Analyse et Décisions Financières</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>7,15</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Informatique Décisionnelle</td>
            <td>
               <span>5</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>9,07</span>
            </td>
            <td>Informatique  Décisionnelle</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>9,45</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Analyse statistique</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>8,50</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Intelligence des affaires</td>
            <td>
               <span>5</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>8,50</span>
            </td>
            <td>Séries Temportelles et Contrôle qualité</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>9,55</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Data Mining</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>7,80</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>projet BI</td>
            <td>
               <span>8</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>11,40</span>
            </td>
            <td>Projet d’apprentissage Business Intelligence</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>11,40</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Projet intégration développement</td>
            <td>
               <span>8</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>15,02</span>
            </td>
            <td>Projet intégration développement</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>15,02</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Recherche opérationnelle</td>
            <td>
               <span>4</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>13,14</span>
            </td>
            <td>Projet RO-complexité</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10,70</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Programmation linéaire</td>
            <td>1,50</td>
            <td>12,30</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Graphes et applications</td>
            <td>1,50</td>
            <td>15,60</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Systéme et service réseaux</td>
            <td>
               <span>4</span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span>10,68</span>
            </td>
            <td>Services et Administration des Réseaux</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>13,85</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Systèmes d'exploitation avancés</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>7,50</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/monster5/pen/vepbzg

update: i found a [jQuery plugin to serialize HTML tables into javascript objects](https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json) but i am having problems using it in my code.
in my ionic 1 app i am scraping a web page and putting the response (the whole page) in a var like this

```
    var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
                tmp.body.innerHTML = response.data;
```

and then i use this to get the table

```
    var table = tmp.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2');
```

this is not working

```
    var table2 = $(table).tableToJSON();
```

it returns an empty list

Comment: Care to post your effort thus far?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you removed unnecessary attributes from the table markup to clarify the actual data and structure, and fix the indentation so people trying to help you don't have to do that work themselves.

Comment: I reformatted the code, please do it next time.

Comment: Are the `<span>`s necessary? And if so, what's in the way of processing them with javascript?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the desired output format. Also, it seems that the rows in the table don't all have the same number of cells, so how would that map to your desired output?

Comment: You want an array of objects, what would be the keys of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a table by finding all rows within the table (using `querySelectorAll('tr')` for example), then iterating over each of these rows and parsing the cells using the same method (`row.querySelectorAll('td')`).

In your case, the first row is the header, so you can first parse the header and use those values as the name of the keys:

```
function parseHeader(header) {
  return [...header.querySelectorAll('th')].map((e) => e.textContent);
}

table = document.querySelector('table'); // Find the table
rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); // get all rows in the table
console.log(parseHeader(rows[0]); // Parse the first row as the header
//=> ["Unite d'Enseignement", "NB_ECTS", "MOYENNE /UE", "MODULES", "COEF", "MOY_MODULE"]
```

Then parse each of the other rows and use the previously parsed header as the key for each of that row:

```
function parseRow(row, header) {
  var obj = {};
  // For each cell, match it with the header in the same index
  // and add it to the object
  row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((e, i) => obj[header[i]] = e.textContent.trim());
  return obj;
}

// Iterate over the rows (skipping the first one which is the header)
const result = [];
for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  // Pass the row and the header array
  // then add the resulting object into the array
  result.push(parseRow(rows[1], header)); 
}
console.log(result);
```

Here's a working example of the code explained above:

https://jsfiddle.net/ssjqwhLq/

Comment: thank you for your answer
your code is working but there is a thing 
take a look here 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ssjqwhLq/1/)
you see Application d'entreprise and Gestion de projet et management they have more than one module in them but your code parse each one alone